# RewriteRule working locally but not when live

Tags: .htaccess, silex

I have a local site (Silex app) set up in the following URL: http://local.exmaple.com/web/index.php

I need to remove the `/web` portion from the url and the following `.htaccess` accomplished this objective well, when placed in the project root (`../web`):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/$1 [L,QSA]
```

In addition to the above local site, I need to set up an identical site on a live server and I need to accomplish the same task of removing `/web/` from the url.

The test site is located in the following:
http://www.otherexample.com/mango/test/web/index.php

While the `.htaccess` works well in the local environment, it fails to remove / redirect to the web directory on the live test site.

I was wondering if anyone knew why this is and how to fix this.

Thank you

Comment: the root of www.otherexample.com and local.example.com are totally different, however  `www.otherexample.com/mango/test/*` and `local.example.com/*` are identical.

Comment: Have you tried to simply add the [```RewriteBase /web/```](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) and remove it from the RewriteRule? (you shouldn't need to put any rewrite rule under the ```web/``` folder)

Comment: Please mark the question as completed....

Comment: Do you need some other help on this topic or not?! If not so, MARK AS COMPLETED

Answer (score 0):

On live server just change your `RewriteRule` to this in site your `mango/test/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule .* web/$0 [L]
```

This is assuming you have a separate .htaccess inside `mango/test/web/` sub-directory.

Comment: thanks for the reply, this did not work however... getting a 404, and I do have a separate .htaccess inside the /web directory which is identical to the one on the local site.

Comment: http://www.otherexample.com/mango/test/web/index.php works and I am trying to have it redirect to http://www.otherexample.com/mango/test/index.php

Comment: yes, and note, I dont just need index.php to work, but any url with /web/, i.e ../test/web/search => ../test/search, ../test/web/index.php => ../test/index.php, ../test/web/results => ../test/results

Comment: accessing the url mango/test should **rewrite** to mango/test/web and recurrently resulting in a 404

Comment: not working, mango/test/web/index.php resolves to mango/test/web/ (keeping web in the url and still working), mango/test/web/search/?q is working, mango/test/search/?q still resulting in a 404

Comment: `http://www.otherexample.com/mango/test/web/search/?q=tst` works, while `http://www.otherexample.com/mango/test/search/?q=tst` results in a Silex page not found error.

Comment: That resolved the 404s but adding /web/ to the url instead of omitting. So now `/mango/test/search/?q=tst` does **not** result in a 404, but rewrites url to `/mango/test/web/search/?q=tst`, adding the `/web/` to the url instead of keeping the url without the `/web/` in the url, while still accessing resources within /web/

Comment: ok that's what I suspected. Rewrite rule is fine but your `silex` framework doesn't work when there is internal rewrite to `web` folder (i.e. URI doesn't change externally).

Comment: that is a normal assumption to make, however, why would it work locally? the htaccess works perfectly with silex locally...

Comment: Because directory structure is different locally. There you have `web` directly under `DocumentRoot` and here it is subdirectory of `mango/test/`

Comment: You need to add this line `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] = preg_replace('~/mango/test/(?!web/)~', '$0web/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);` in your `index.php` just above `require_once __DIR__.'/../../../vendor/autoload.php';` and retest.

Comment: I have downloaded and setup Silex using **exact** same directory structure and placed silex `web` folder inside `DocumentRoot/mango/test/`. When I made the change in `index.php` as I suggested everything worked fine for me and I can access `http://localhost/mango/test/qwerty`  that shows same content as of `http://localhost/mango/test/web/qwerty`

Comment: This approach you are proposing is a hack, I need to keep my work within htaccess and implement a url rewrite, I am not allowed to override global variables, thank you though... the real question is how come the local htaccess is short and sweet and working and on live I need to implement a whole separate solution instead of using the same htaccess / or a slightly modified one...?

Comment: First you wrote **that didnt work** and when I provided proof of a working model you are saying a different reason :) good luck

Comment: No I am not, you've diverged from the original question so much that your solution solves a totally different problem, not what was original asked, I appreciate the effort though. thank you

Comment: It has solved the exact problem stated in question and it is working on my Apache but yes it involves adding one line of php code as well not 100% from .htaccess.

Comment: lol its using a preg replace and overriding a global variable, its witchcraft voodoo :D it is possible to handle this issue solely form htaccess and that is the solution i am after, as stated in the original question ;)

Comment: **it is possible to handle this issue solely form htaccess** yes I am also willing to learn that 100% .htaccess solution using Silex fraework. btw it is not just silex, many other PHP framework like Wordpress, Joomla etc won't work without any PHP change.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether your problem is solved or not already. So I'll give you my solution since I've had the same problem you have.

In my opinion, you just have to make this small adjustment:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [L]
```

As you said: place it in the root document of your project. Also, something to check that might be a problem is your other .htaccess located in your /web folder. Make sure these are the lines of code that redirect to your index.php file:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Then, last but not least, how did you assign the routes? Because, when you enable debugging, which I'll assume you did, you can get a 'this route is not found' message. That might be because you assigned the routes wrong. And do not say that I'm wrong, since I've had exactly the same problem. When using the project on XAMPP is had to assign them like 'Project/public/#route' but when I were in my server I were obliged to assign them like '#route'.

So, to fix that, I suggest the following solution:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Silex\Application();
$app['debug'] = true;

$routes = $app['controllers_factory'];
```

Now, assign your routes like the following example:

```
$routes->match('/', function (Request $request) use ($app) {

    return $app['twig']->render('home.twig');

})->bind('home');
```

Close your index.php with the following lines of code:

```
$app->mount('#baseURL', $routes);
$app->run();
```

You should try some values for #baseURL, on your local server it might me the following:

```
$app->mount('/', $routes);
```

And on your webserver try:

```
$app->mount('/Project/', $routes);
$app->mount('/Project/web/', $routes);
```

Please let me know whether this solved your problem. If so, mark as completed, otherwise, please comment with the new problems!

### Edit

It's not a problem to use something like this:

```
$routes->get('/', function (Request $request) use ($app) {

    return $app['twig']->render('home.twig');

})->bind('home');
```

You just need to use $routes, instead of $app

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Why do I need to assign my routes as you explained? what if I need http functions, i.e. get, post, etc?

Comment: Oh no, that's not a problem, you can just do the get and post methods. The difference is in the $routes part, which we assign later with a different (bigger) URL. Does it work when you use this mounting method? P.s. I've edited my answer for you!